# SQL match the column's value with all values of other columns EXCEPT values

Tags: mysql

I have only one table: *products*

```
ID | Product Name | Code 1 | Code 2 | Code 3
********************************************
1  |    Phone1    |   MM   |   DD   |   nd
2  |    Phone2    |   DD   |        |   nd
3  |    Phone3    |   MM   |   ZZ   |   nd
4  |    Phone4    |   XX   |        |   nd
```

I'd like to:

> select all phones which one of their codes match one of the
>   *Phone1*'s code **BUT NOT IF THE CODE = ND**

So it should return *Phone2* and *Phone3* but now it returns them all.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84787/1) (thanks to [@JamieD77](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221684/jamied77))

I assume I should use something like this? But can't place it properly:

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT p1.`Product Name` 
 FROM `products` p1 
 WHERE
 p.`Product Name` = 'nd')
```

I believe there's something simpler to tell MySQL to exclude certain values in every column when it comes to finding matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by just returning 'Phone1'.  We have the `id` value handily available, so we can use that. We could also use the `product_name` column.

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.product_name
      , p.code_1
      , p.code_2
      , p.code_3
   FROM products p
  WHERE p.id = 1
```

Easy enough.

Now to find phones with "matching" codes. We can start with joining the `products` table to itself.

Phone1 is going to match itself on one of it's codes. (Assuming there's at least one non-NULL and non-'nd' code.) We'll assume that we don't want to return Phone1, so we can exclude that in the join predicate... only return rows where the `id` value is different.

To find a matching code, we can compare code_1 from the candidate phone with code_1, code_2 and code_3 of Phone1, to see if any of those are equal. We can do the same thing for code_2 and code_3 of the candidate phone.

The spec does tell us that `nd` is not to be considered a matching code, so we can shortcut the comparison, if the code_N we're comparing is equal to 'nd'.

From the spec, it's not clear if we want to consider an empty string or blanks, to equal another code that is blanks or empty string. (We can't tell if those empty codes are NULL values, zero length strings, or a space.)

And, obviously, we want to return the columns from the "matching" phones, not from the Phone1 row.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
 SELECT o.id
      , o.product_name
      , o.code_1
      , o.code_2
      , o.code_3
   FROM products p
   JOIN products o
     ON o.id <> p.id 
    AND (  (o.code_1 <> 'nd' AND o.code_1 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) ) 
        OR (o.code_2 <> 'nd' AND o.code_2 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
        OR (o.code_3 <> 'nd' AND o.code_3 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
        )
  WHERE p.id = 1
```

With the conditions in the join predicates, a `NULL` value in o.code_N won't match a `NULL` value in p.code_N. If we also want to disregard matches of empty strings, we can tweak the conditions a bit:

```
    AND (  (o.code_1 NOT IN ('nd','') AND o.code_1 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) ) 
        OR (o.code_2 NOT IN ('nd','') AND o.code_2 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
        OR (o.code_3 NOT IN ('nd','') AND o.code_3 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
        )
```

In terms of performance, this probably won't win any races.

And this isn't the only query pattern that will return the specified result. We could write a query that uses an `EXISTS` clause, to accomplish the same thing:

```
 SELECT o.id
      , o.product_name
      , o.code_1
      , o.code_2
      , o.code_3
   FROM products o
  WHERE EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
           FROM phones p
          WHERE p.id = 1
            AND o.id <> p.id
            AND (  (o.code_1 <> 'nd' AND o.code_1 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) ) 
                OR (o.code_2 <> 'nd' AND o.code_2 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
                OR (o.code_3 <> 'nd' AND o.code_3 IN (p.code_1,p.code_2,p.code_3) )
                )
        )
```

And we could re-write that to (likely) be more performant, if appropriate indexes are available.

---

In terms of something simpler, the SQL would be written differently if `Code 1`, `Code 2` and `Code 3` for a phone were stored as separate rows in another table:

```
phone_code

phone_id  code_num  code_val
       1         1  MM
       1         2  DD
       1         3  nd
       2         1  DD
       2         2  
       2         3  nd
       3         1  MM
       3         2  ZZ
       3         3  nd
       4         1  XX
       4         2  
       4         3  nd
```

If the data were structured that way, the SQL code would be quite a bit different.